# How to pass Arraylist key to server using GSON (Serilized("image"))

Tags: android

I am passing image `arrayObject` to server using GSON, below is my `serializedName` and key for this. Hope somebody helps me.

```
@SerializedName("image")
private ArrayList<MarketPlaceImage> marketPlaceImages;

public ProductReturnFormInput() {
    marketPlaceImages = new ArrayList<>();
}

public ArrayList<MarketPlaceImage> getMarketPlaceImages() {
    return marketPlaceImages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@SerializedName("image")
private ArrayList<MarketPlaceImage> marketPlaceImages;
```

When you do this,**image** is considered as key.